# How to flag a user editing tag wiki

Tags: support, tags, review, suggested-edits

This particular [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2982225/payeli) seems to be on a tag wiki editing spree. I've noticed quite a few tag edits which are very trivial and offer very less information. And I happened to see quite a lot of the tag wiki edits in the reviews queue even today.

My question is, how do I flag such an user for moderator attention? Because there is no flag option in the review page of a tag wiki edit, nor does the tag page have an option to flag.

Comment: Those edits are all *excerpts*; so I'd expect those to be short.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The user has done only [wiki edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2982225/payeli?tab=activity) until now.  I imagine that it might not be possible to find a post by the user.

Comment: But you can flag _any_ post @devnull, just make sure that you explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @devnull: There are posts; I checked first. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The user is creating Wiki Excerpts, the short, plain-text descriptions of tags that appear in the tag tooltip and at the top of tag pages.

The edits all look entirely appropriate and useful to me, I see no reason to stop this user. This is good and useful work!

Comment: These reviews are done by *loads* of users. At some point you are going to have to trust the review system here.

Comment: If you take that attitude @R.J then what's the point in anyone doing anything? You have to trust people at _some_ point and then come up with a way of cleaning up the mess if it becomes necessary.