# tag editing is broken -- tag edits on beta sites get rejected and you get blocked

Tags: discussion, support, bug, tags, suggested-edits

I think the tag editing is fundamentally broken, especially on beta sites.

[Why in tag edits, only the full wiki is approved, and excerpt/usage rejected?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/why-in-tag-edits-only-the-full-wiki-is-approved-and-excerpt-usage-rejected) documents that a whole bunch of tag excerpts are rejected for the following (non-)reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. See the help center for more guidance.

***Now is it really?***

Do people really know what ***TAA*** is? Or what ["***prima facie***"](https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1079) stands for?  Or [***CDDL***](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1352)?  Or [***Georgia***](https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2238)?

On Law, it was later revealed that my edits to *jurisdiction* tags would have been approved had I simply prefixed the tag with "*Questions relating to*" and postfix with "*jurisdiction*", as if anyone visiting Law might be confused whether tags refer to questions, or geographic localities to jurisdictions.  E.g., it's somehow more important to know that "Canada" refers to "questions" in a "jurisdiction" (regardless whether in Oklahoma, Kansas or Kentucky!), instead of a country which is further divided into X provinces and territories.

On OSS, after 5 of my 6 tag edits were rejected (within a period of a single minute), I'm now blocked from doing any further edits!

Comment: In general, if Google can provide a better definition, then your tag wiki excerpt is probably useless.

Comment: I looked up the [meta discussion on Law](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/252/why-in-tag-edits-only-the-full-wiki-is-approved-and-excerpt-usage-rejected), and in fact the ♦ mod rejecting specifically said that the "Questions relating to"/"jurisdiction" boilerplate was entirely irrelevant to their decision. You should strike that from your post, as it is a factually incorrect assertion.

Comment: This [law.se] businees will get out of control. It will get out of control and we'll be lucky to live through it. (RIP Fred)

Comment: @NathanTuggy, it was more than one person that was rejecting edits like these, and if you look at the history of all of these tags, later edits that simply had "For questions related to X jurisdiction", for tag X -- which is indeed probably worse than no tag excerpt at all -- were all promptly approved.  Yet here we are, -8 for bringing up this issue here on meta SE!

Comment: How is this not a hypocrisy? http://opensource.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1352 http://opensource.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1358 Why when people include "For questions relating to", providing a less useful summary, their edits get approved?

Comment: @cnst: Like I said, it's broken: it's too easy to get terrible edits approved.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, no, the problem is that it's more difficult to get good edits approved, whereas "for questions relating to tag" get approved with stellar frequency; also, did you miss the part that after those 3 edits (5/6 being rejected), ***i'm blocked from editing ANY tags (even doing any suggested edits at all!) on OSS***?

Comment: @cnst: The problem is that, while you can quite reasonably object to all the bad edits being approved, you have very few rejected good edits on hand as a counter. I would have rejected all five of those OSS edits.

Answer (score 3):

Tag wiki editing is broken, yes, but none of your examples are shining beacons of glorious enlightenment. I can't say for sure (since I don't know a lot about Law), but it looks like those can probably all be categorized as Wikipedia-style excerpts for reasonably common knowledge topics. Unfortunately, a snippet from Wikipedia is *not helpful* in usage guidance; if a reasonably well-informed poster or editor on that site should be expected to have a good idea what a tag means from its name (Georgia, Canada, CDDL, prima facie), there really is very little need for an excerpt at all.

And when an excerpt *is* needed, having cruft there already (subtly confusing everyone who sees those examples of useless excerpts) just tends to warp excerpts away from their real purpose — to clarify obscure tag names, disambiguate tags, and prevent ubiquitous tags from being overused. Guidance that does *that* is actually rather difficult to write, and any distractions or confusions are especially dangerous. In particular, it's pretty much useless in most cases to write usage guidance without referring frequently and almost exclusively to the list of questions tagged accordingly at present.

Finally, [a blank tag wiki is an irreplaceable resource at present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208190/allow-deleting-a-tag-wiki-or-excerpt). Don't waste it on something pedestrian; save it for a really solid, really essential writeup.

Comment: How exactly is someone supposed to know what Georgia and Canada means?  TAA, likewise, has many distinct results on Google as well.  You're kind of having a straw man argument here.

Comment: @cnst: "Canada", on a site about Law, can really only mean one thing. Yes? No? Anything else it can refer to? "Georgia" is a little less awesome; it can refer to either the country or the American state, but given that, simply pointing out "Georgia, the state in America" is a good idea, but the rest ... no. "TAA"... debatable, but I'm not terribly thrilled with the barebones result that came up. That's not nearly as clear-cut as the others, though.

Comment: no, there's at least more than one city named Canada, and there's no reason to believe that none of them have any jurisdiction over anyone visiting the site; a tag like "Canada" with the exemplary tag excerpt like "For questions relating to the jurisdiction of Canada" (I wish I was making these dummy excerpts up!), would apply to all of such cities.  Then what's the purpose of tags if they're just keywords "for questions relating to" with no unique meaning?

Comment: @cnst: I would expect individual cities to have, in general, no tag at all. If they *did* have a tag, one with a more precise name would make sense. (`canada-tx`, or whatever.) There is no reason at all to suppose that the tag named just `canada` would refer to a specific city or county by that name. That's just not how tag naming works.

Comment: straw man again; if someone lives in Canada Kansas, the way things are, they have no reason to believe that using two tags, `canada` and `kansas` is wrong; in fact, excerpts explicitly tell them it's ok to just stick with `canada` alone.

Comment: @cnst: That's not what "straw man" means, and since I've explicitly stated that the sort of excerpt that would tell them that is a bad excerpt, I don't know why you're trying to argue against that assertion... which is, in fact, **actually** a straw man argument that you need to stop using.