# How can a moderator clear a tag wiki or excerpt?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, plagiarism

From time to time, we come across plagiarized content in tag wikis or excerpts that we want to delete.  Ideally, we'd rewrite it to something non-plagiarized, but we're not subject-matter experts on every subject, and we don't always have time to research it enough to write one with useful usage guidance.

Unfortunately, trying to edit out all the content results in an error:
[image: "Wiki Excerpt is missing." error]

Apparently, it is sometimes possible to [do a rollback to an empty first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269999/165261); however, this option isn't always available:
[image: One revision, with only "Source, Edit, Edit comment, Link, and Redact options]

How can a moderator reliably delete the content of a tag wiki or excerpt?

Comment: Pro tip: You can change it to "Apparently, this tag wiki excerpt prefers to keep an air of mystery about it."

Comment: Related feature request: [Allow deleting a tag wiki or excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208190/335251)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tags whose first real revision was a suggested edit will have a blank first revision, attributed to Community, that you can roll back to without any fuss. For tags whose first revision was submitted as a binding edit by a user with 20k+ reputation, though, that's not an option, so you need a bit of a more convoluted method. This will remove both the main tag wiki and the usage guidance (excerpt), though; if you want to preserve one of them, you'll need to either save the text somewhere or find it later at /admin/orphan-wikis.

This has been tested and proven to work. There are three main steps:

1. First, create a new tag with a blank excerpt. It does have to be added to a question for this to work. So, for example, create a new tag [tag-wiki-fix](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-fix) on a question.
2. Secondly, merge the tag with the plagiarized wiki into the new tag. If [william-shakespeare](/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare) has the plagiarized wiki, merge [william-shakespeare](/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare) into [tag-wiki-fix](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-fix).

   This can be done from /admin/merge-tags. Set the tag with the wiki you want to remove (i.e., [william-shakespeare](/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare)) as the "source tag" and the new tag you just created ([tag-wiki-fix](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-fix)) as the "target tag".

   [image: Screenshot of the merge tags tool, showing william-shakespeare as the source tag and tag-wiki-fix as the target.]
3. Thirdly, merge them back the other way - rename [tag-wiki-fix](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-fix) to [william-shakespeare](/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare). As with a normal tag rename, you don't need to actually add the properly named tag to a question for this step.

These steps will orphan the tag wiki that was originally at [william-shakespeare](/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare), leaving you with a blank wiki. The removed tag wiki and excerpt can then be found at /admin/orphan-wikis (unless that page happens to be broken or overloaded).