# How do I write an accessible Stack Exchange post?

Tags: discussion, accessibility

Accessibility is important for making sure that posts and content on the Stack Exchange network can be read and understood by as many people as possible, including people with disabilities. Because the goal of the network is to share information, it's best to make sure that that information can help as many people as possible.

When writing or editing a question, answer, or other type of post on the Stack Exchange network, how can I make sure that the post is as accessible as possible to people with disabilities?

Comment: why did you tag it as [discussion]? I think it should be tagged as [support]. Isn't it?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Most [tag:faq]'s are indeed tagged support, but some are discussion it doesn't really matter. But why no [tag:faq-proposed] tag? Mith?

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry Because this isn't a *frequently asked* question. In fact, I don't think I've seen any questions on MSE since I've started here asking about how to write accessible posts ;) (Not counting that one post asking about whether there is such a post).

Comment: @Tinkeringbell well, it should be then as it's useful and important. Having this as simple self answered question will make it hard to find. There are great many topics already in the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), adding another one won't clutter it, and IMO would be useful.

Comment: Realistically, hardly anyone who assembles a "FAQ" is informed by a prior analysis of how FA the Qs are. (Hence people tongue-in-cheekly offering IAQs instead.)

Comment: useful, important, and likely to go unread/unused by effectively everyone, ;)

Answer (score 20):

This short guide goes over several aspects of accessibility to keep in mind when writing or editing posts on the Stack Exchange network. There are many different disabilities out there, and these tips cover accessibility for many of them, such as people using screen readers, keyboard users, colorblind users, and people with cognitive disabilities.

---

### Formatting

#### Headings

Headings are used to separate sections of information. Each heading should give you a decent indication of what you can expect in that section. (As an example, the heading "headings" before this section is a good hint that this section is about headings.)

Follow an intuitive header order. Don't jump from an `<h2>` to an `<h5>`; follow a consistent, intuitive order for headings, where top-level sections have a higher-level header and sub-sections have a lower-level header. You shouldn't skip levels of headings (for instance, moving from an `<h2>` to an `<h4>` without an `<h3>` in between)
However, when you are ending a sub-section and moving back to a higher-level section, you can move from a low-level header (such as `<h4>`) back up to a higher-level header (such as `<h2>`) without including a mid-level header.

There should generally only be one top-level header (which can be formatted using `<h1>` or `#`) per-page. Stack Exchange posts generally have a top-level heading as the question title.
Whether or not using another top-level header is appropriate depends on the type of post you're writing, as well as on how the question and answers are structured. Posts covering a large number of topics or that are split up into multiple, entirely distinct sections sometimes might need to include more than one top-level heading, but consider carefully if it's actually necessary.

Only use headings for actual headings, and don't use headings for non-header content. If something acts as a heading, it should be properly marked up as a heading, using either the appropriate Markdown or HTML tags. The opposite holds true as well; if something is not acting as a heading, it should not be formatted as a heading. If you want to emphasize something, don't use headings to do that.

Screen readers and similar can jump from heading to heading (including describing what level of heading), so keep that in mind when choosing headings for your posts.

---

##### Examples

A good heading order follows the logical layout of the page, without skipping over levels, consistently uses the same level headings for sections at the same level, and only uses headings for actual heading content.

```
<h1>Question title (automatically provided)<h1>
<h2>Answer section 1</h2>
<h3>Answer sub-section 1a</h3>
<h3>Answer sub-section 1b</h3>
<h2>Answer section 2</h2>
<h3>Answer sub-section 2a</h3>
<h3>Answer sub-section 2b</h3>
<h4>Answer sub-sub-section 2b.1</h4>
<h4>Answer sub-sub-section 2b.2</h4>
<h2>Answer section 3</h2>
```

The heading order above shows an answer that doesn't use a top-level heading (`<h1>`), since there's already one on the page - the question title. It uses `<h2>` to differentiate its high-level sections. It then uses `<h3>` for the sub-sections, and when it's necessary to have a sub-sub-section, it uses `<h4>`.

A bad heading order would skip levels, use headings for non-heading content, or unnecessarily over-use top-level headings.

```
<h1>Question title (automatically provided)</h1>
<h1>Answer summary (actual content)</h1>
<h3>Answer section 1</h3>
<h5>Answer sub-section 1a</h5>
<h4>Answer sub-section 1b</h4>
<h2>Answer section 2</h2>
<h4>Notes</h4>
<h1>Thank you for reading!</h1>
```

This bad example uses `<h1>` twice in the answer, despite there already being a top-level heading as the question title. It uses an `<h1>` heading for the answer summary, using a heading for non-heading content. It then uses wildly inconsistent heading levels for its different sections and sub-sections, and skips levels of headings (such as moving directly from `<h3>` to `<h5>`).

---

#### Emphasized text

Emphasized text, such as bold or italics, is good for calling attention to key words or sentences. However, if it's overused, it ends up defeating its own purpose and making a post more difficult to read instead of clearer.

Bold text should be used sparingly. Only use it to highlight words or sentences that actually need special attention called to them.

Italics should only be used when it is appropriate to use italics, such as for emphasizing stress on a certain word, italicizing the names of works, and other standard uses of italics. Don't over-use italics on text that doesn't need to be italicized; remember that italics can make it harder to read the text for certain people, including some people with dyslexia.

Avoid bolding or italicizing entire paragraphs.

#### Code markup

Code markup should be used for code, including variable names and other code elements that may be found in non-code lines. This allows for code highlighting to work, and makes it clear when a code element is being referred to.

Code markup should not be used for any non-code elements. This includes using it for emphasis, for tables, or other non-code usage. Instead, use the [dedicated formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for those elements. Misusing code markup can cause issues for assistive technology such as screen readers.

#### Text size

Don't stack subscripts or superscripts to make your text tiny. Using superscript or subscript once is enough, and only use it when necessary.<sup>1</sup> Screen readers may not differentiate between sub- or superscript and regular text, so keep that in mind.

#### Tables

Stack Exchange doesn't currently provide any way to specify the scope of headers in tables, so you should generally avoid putting ambiguous data into tables - i.e., having data that you can't tell which column of the table it would be associated with without checking, such as having two columns containing plain numbers.
Avoid blank header rows in tables, and don't use table formatting for data that doesn't actually belong in a table.

### Images

#### Alternative (alt) text

Whenever you include an image in a post, you should include alternative text that serves the same purpose as the image. This replaces the default text "enter image description here". This is used by screen readers, search engines, and when images can't be displayed (such as images being blocked in certain countries or by school/business networks).

The alt text should be short, succinct, and serve the exact same purpose as the image - it shouldn't contain more or less information than the image itself.
As a general way of making sure your alt text is appropriate, consider if the information present in the post would change at all if the image was replaced entirely with the alt text. If the information would stay the same, you're good to go.

#### Decorative images

A decorative image, which serves no purpose other than visual, should have its alt text be entirely blank. (Note that this is *blank*, not *missing*. From a coding perspective, this means setting its `alt` attribute to `=""`, not leaving out the `alt` attribute.)

By default, images uploaded to Stack Exchange become links, and Stack Exchange does not natively support any way to mark an image as decorative, which means leaving the alt text blank results in screen readers reading out the image URL or link instead of skipping over it. In general, you should avoid including images that don't serve any specific purpose or that are just decorative in your post.

If you find yourself including a decorative image, make sure to remove the link, leaving only the embedded image, and to set the alt text to be blank.

#### Stable resource (Stack Imgur)

In order to avoid the possibility of dead images, and ensure that that post remains stable for as long as possible, you should avoid using an external image hosting service. Instead, use the built-in Stack Imgur image uploader. External image hosting services includes the regular Imgur service; that service isn't guaranteed to retain images in the same way.

---

##### Examples

Let's take the following snippet of a post for our example:

> This can be done from /admin/merge-tags. Set the tag with the wiki you want to remove (i.e., [william-shakespeare](/questions/tagged/william-shakespeare)) as the "source tag" and the new tag you just created ([tag-wiki-fix](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki-fix)) as the "target tag".
>
> [image: Screenshot of the merge tags tool, showing william-shakespeare as the source tag and tag-wiki-fix as the target.]
> <sub>(Source: Answer to "[How can a moderator clear a tag wiki or excerpt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378351/294691)" on Meta Stack Exchange, by Mithical)</sub>

In this example, the image is being used to illustrate the proper fields to put the tags into. That information needs to be presented in the alt text as well, which the current alt text does:

`[![Screenshot of the merge tags tool, showing william-shakespeare as the source tag and tag-wiki-fix as the target.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6arlH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6arlH.png)`

This is short and to the point. It tells anybody who can't see the image which field to put each tag in, which is why the screenshot was included.

A bad example would be leaving out the alt text, having overly long alt text, or relying on an external image hosting service:

`[![](https://i.imgur.com/dVDBN6G.png)](https://i.imgur.com/dVDBN6G.png)`

`[![Screenshot of the merge tags tool, which can be found at /admin/merge-tags and is linked from /admin/links. It's showing william-shakespeare as the source tag, with the note "This tag will be remapped to the target specified below on all existing questions.", and tag-wiki-fix as the target.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6arlH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6arlH.png)`

In the first bad example, there is both no alt text and it relies on an external image service. There is no information presented to anyone who can't see the image, and there's the risk that the image will go dead even for people who can see it.
In the second bad example, the alt text is too long. It has information that's not present in the image itself, such as where to find the page, and describes information that's not relevant to the purpose of the screenshot - which is simply to show the correct fields to place each tag in.

---

#### Don't rely solely on color

When your image uses colors to indicate a difference between things - such as on a chart or graph - you should also use a different method of differentiating, such as an icon or different shape. Also avoid using colors that are known to be a problem for colorblind users (such as red/green).

#### Contrast

Avoid colors that are too close to each other, especially for text on a background color. As a simple way of testing, take a glance at the image in sunlight - can you still make it out?

#### Animations

Stack Exchange doesn't currently support any way to disable or pause animations in posts, so avoid using animations where possible. In particular, make sure to avoid flashing content (especially anything flashing more than three times a second - don't do that!). Flashing content can cause seizures, and looping animations can be distracting for everyone, but especially for people with some cognitive disabilities.

#### Images of text

Avoid images of text. Images of text can't have the text selected, be read by screen readers, indexed by search engines, have the text adjust in a responsive design, or have the font changed. This includes images of code; instead, put the actual code in your post and format it using the [dedicated code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

If you are quoting from somewhere, use blockquote formatting (which can be done by putting a `>` at the beginning of a paragraph) and cite your source. This applies to both online and offline resources, such as Wikipedia or a physical book.
Do not use code formatting for quotes.

### Links

#### Link text

Avoid link text such as "Here" or "Read more". The link should explain its purpose through the text itself. Remember that screen readers and similar tools can jump to specific links, but if they're named something like "this", navigating to the correct link is much harder.
Don't go too far in the other direction, though; there's no need to make an entire sentence a link as long as the link text is descriptive and distinct.
In general, link text should be unique - don't use the same link text twice in one post if those links go to different places.

#### Stable resource (Web Archive)

While not required by any standard that I'm aware of, I'd encourage you to take steps to make sure that any resource you link to remains stable by archiving it in the Web Archive when you link to it. (This is similar to what Wikipedia does; sources used in articles are almost always archived so that a backup exists.) Glorfindel's [Archiver userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8386/43962) makes this convenient, by adding a button to archive all links in a post, so you can create a Web Archive backup for all pages linked in your post with a single click.

### Making your posts understandable

#### Vocabulary

In general, try to keep your vocabulary simple. This doesn't mean avoiding all technical terms, or not using the correct terms for things, but don't use jargon or fancy words when it's not necessary. This makes it easier for people who don't speak English as their first language, or people with cognitive disabilities, to understand your post.

This should not come at the expense of precision or accuracy, though; keep your audience in mind. If you're writing a post on [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), you're probably going to use a lot of fancy terms, but a post on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) probably doesn't need to.

#### Define acronyms and specialized terms

The first time you use an acronym, you should fully spell out what you're referring to. A common example found on Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) is just that - the acronym MSE. However, even in the context of the Stack Exchange network, that acronym can also refer to Math Stack Exchange or other Stack Exchange sites, as well as having meanings unrelated to the network. Once you've defined what MSE stands for in your post, you can continue to use the acronym.

This applies to specialized terms, jargon, and words in other languages as well. The first time you use a specialized term, define what it means or translate it.

#### Paragraph and sentence breaks

Avoid walls of text.
Make sure to break up your posts into sections, paragraphs, and sentences. When something runs on for too long, or is too dense, it can be very hard for people to get through, especially people who don't speak the language well or people with certain cognitive disabilities.

---

And those are the top tips for making your post accessible! Remember that accessibility is an ongoing process, so don't feel too bad if not all of your posts meet these guidelines. They can always be edited later, and the important thing is to keep accessibility in mind as you go forwards writing and editing posts.

---

<sup>1</sup> Such as for footnotes, although Stack Exchange doesn't have built-in support for Markdown footnotes. In general, they should be kept to a minimum, since scrolling up and down to access footnotes can be confusing.

Comment: Thank you to [Laurel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/323179/laurel) and [SpencerG](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1046749/spencerg) for looking this over before it was posted.

Comment: Should quote attributions really be placed *inside* the blockquote element (as seen in the example)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific accessibility standards on that, @Elements. I think it comes down to personal preference. I usually put it inside the block quote to clearly associate it with the quoted content and to visually put them together.

Comment: [Italic / oblique fonts have a variety of uses.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1294/194233) Stress emphasis (which can [affect meaning quite a lot](https://designerlessons.org/2011/12/10/intonation-sentence-stress-esl/)) should use whatever maps to the `<em>` tag (currently, the Markdown does, though you can also write the tag), and the offsetting of titles etc. should use `<i>`: the paragraph about emphasis seems to mainly apply to `<b>` / `<strong>`. Also, this post uses line breaks (`<br />`) a lot where I'd use bullet points.

Comment: @Mithical "I usually put it inside the block quote to clearly associate it with the quoted content and to visually put them together." As to the "visually", this makes no difference to the visually impaired. I tend to place the attribution before the blockquote so that the visually impaired reader knows what's coming next.

Comment: As for emphasized text, what I have come to understand is that the use of text that is both bold and italics is difficult for users with dyslexia.

Comment: @agarza - For citations, all of the style guides I found indicate that attribution comes after the quotation when citing a work or website, usually as a parenthetical. While the visual indication doesn't help the visually impaired, it does help other people - such as myself - to more clearly associate the citation with the quotation. I'm not aware of any particular accessibility guidelines on that specific point, but I'm happy to be corrected about that.

Comment: According to the [style guide for dyslexia](https://www.bdadyslexia.org.uk/advice/employers/creating-a-dyslexia-friendly-workplace/dyslexia-friendly-style-guide), it looks like italics in general can make it harder to read, but it doesn't specifically point out stacking bold and italics. It advises using bold for emphasis but to avoid italics.

Comment: I'll try to revise the emphasized text section soon, @wizzwizz4, to more clearly spell out appropriate and inappropriate uses of italics (including the information from the page about dyslexia linked above).

Comment: "you should avoid putting ambiguous data into tables…data that you can't tell which column of the table it would be associated with without checking". This is only really an issue for tables that don't fit on the page, which is quite small on mobile. There's not really a good alternative however unless you can delete some data so it does fit better. (OTOH, screen readers navigate even these long, unwieldy tables with ease; I used VoiceOver to help me navigate A Year in Closing and it was fantastic.)

Comment: @Mithical That advice might be good for dyslexia, but [it's not generally applicable](https://accessible-digital-documents.com/blog/banning-italics/); bold also has problems. We can't do one-size-fits-all, so I tend to fall back to the HTML semantics, where `<strong>` is for importance, `<b>` is for catching the eye, `<em>` is for stress-emphasis in prose, `<mark>` is for (emphasis mine), and `<i>` is for most other stuff. In the distant future where computers actually work properly, you'll be able to configure your browser to map HTML's semantics to a presentation that works for your brain.

Comment: Btw I remember reading a complaint on mSO that `<code>` triggered some screen readers to spell the contents out (like CSS `speak-as: spell-out`, instead of the more sensible `literal-punctuation`). Your bad alt text examples _are_ clearer when presented in monospace (at least, to me), but they don't have code semantics. Considering you can't use CSS or aria attributes, I don't know what the right solution here is.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "code triggered some screen readers to spell the contents out"—Correct, but I would expect most users to use the middle ground settings. For me, source code is spoken the same as regular text except all punctuation is spoken too, so it will pronounce words as words, not spell them out. If I did need something spelled out, I could switch to "character" mode instead of using "container" mode. (Maybe I should write a guide explaining how a person uses a screen reader?) Anyway, I think monospaced is appropriate for the examples, which are markdown code.

Comment: If your table is available in Excel use [this](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) simple VBA routine to convert the table to Markdown.

Comment: Is there a readily available screen reader that will work with SE sites?

Comment: [Here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/what-are-some-consensus-recommendations-for-screenreader-readability-formatting) is a discussion of suitable formatting for screen readers

Comment: @user10186832 That's a solid "maybe", depending on your other requirements (e.g. operating system). You could ask a separate question about that; and maybe it'll encourage the company to add it to their "supported browser configurations" list.